# Finding optimal regularisation amount when using full rank starting point

Tags: regression

The starting point is full rank 1-dimension interpolation (using a spline or radial basis) where matching all data points. Want now to introduce some regularisation to smooth the fit to the data. A decision to make is how large the regularisation input should be. What is a good automatic way to determine the quantity of regularisation when the basis functions ate full rank? Basic approach’s such as using PRESS statistic or GCV do not work well as there are no errors at starting point which is interpolation.

Is there a good simple way you to proceed ?

Comment: I would question anyone claiming they had a "good automatic way" unless it accounted for your objectives: how much smoothing do you need and why?